# webview reload to home page when switching between activities

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

hello im makeing a vwe browser app and it have a faw problem and dont know which part of the code i post

1. bookmark activity when i go to the bookmark activity it opens fine but when i switch back to the webview it reload to the homepage not the last page it was in PS it don't reloads when the screen change Orientation
2. its kind of slow
3. open videos like youtube but don't let them go full screen

   ourview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
   ourview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   ourview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
   ourview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
   ourview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
   ourview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
   ourview.getSettings().getAllowFileAccess();
   ourview.getSettings().getAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs();
   ourview.getSettings().getJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically();
   ourview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
   ourview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

Answer (score 0):

Switching between different activities,will always call onCreate() method.
So since your `ourview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");` is in onCreate() method,
it is called each time when you switch between those activities.
That is why webView reload to homepage when switching between activities.

Comment: that didn't work my project have only 2 classes and the one with the webview have 307 line in it i don't know how to share it can i share my project some way private